# Postgres psycopg2 create user

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

To create a user through psycopg2, I am using the following code :

```
        cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("create user %s with password %s",('abcdefgh','0h/9warrAttrgd8EF0gkvQ==',))
```

This gives the following error :

```
syntax error at or near "'abcdefgh'" LINE 1: create user 'abcdefgh' with password '0h/9warrAttrgd8EF0gkvQ.
```

It seems that %s is placing quotes around the username, which postgres doesn't like while creating a user. The following code works fine :

```
        cur.execute("create user abcdefgh with password %s",('0h/9warrAttrgd8EF0gkvQ==',))
```

Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 9):

None of the existing answers actually use a safe method of doing this. However, since version 2.7 of Psycopg, there is a much better method.

What the docs say about using `%s` for identifiers (table names, user names etc):

> Only query values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to merge table or field names to the query (Psycopg will try quoting the table name as a string value, generating invalid SQL). If you need to generate dynamically SQL queries (for instance choosing dynamically a table name) you can use the facilities provided by the psycopg2.sql module

Using this module, the above query is better formulated as:

```py
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL("CREATE USER {username} WITH PASSWORD {password}").format(
    username=sql.Identifier('abcdefgh'),
    password=sql.Placeholder()
)
cur.execute(query, ('0h/9warrAttrgd8EF0gkvQ==',))
```

Using https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 2):

Use [`psycopg2.extensions.AsIs(object):`](http://psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs)

```python
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

cur.execute("create user %s with password %s", (AsIs('abcdefgh'), '0h/9warrAttrgd8EF0gkvQ==',))
```

Comment: `with encrypted password` is a better thing

Comment: `encrypted` is default for recent versions.

Comment: Although if you're not sure that the username is actually a valid identifier, I suppose you'd prefer [`quote_ident`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident).

Comment: @Migwell - I don't see any reason a developer should not know if a string is a valid identifier. If he wants to use a quoted identifier nothing prevents him from using double-quotes, e.g. `AsIs('"NewUser"')`