# Create PostgreSQL Role/User from within Python program

Tags: python, postgresql, powershell, roles, asyncpg

Do you know if it's possible to create a role/user for the Postgresql database from within Python code?

I would prefer to use `asyncpg` library, since my program is based on asynchronous code, but if there are better libraries for this specific task, I don't mind using them.

I already have a pre-installed database on my server machine, so another possibility would be to just run the Shell command from withing the Python program to create a role. However, I am not sure if you can create a role in just one Shell line.

Comment: maybe with psycopg2

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar How would the `CREATE ROLE` query look like there? And do you know for sure that psycopg2 supports role creations? I couldn't find definitive answers in their docs.

Comment: psycopg2  is a client for python ...here there is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022587/postgres-psycopg2-create-user

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Thanks! I think I found an even more elegant 1-line solution to my problem: `pool.execute("CREATE ROLE name ...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, the answer appeared to be very straightforward:

`pool.execute("CREATE ROLE name ...")`