# I want to create a user for postgresql using python psycopg2.sql module

Tags: postgresql

This is the code.

```
def create_user(self, id: str, password: str):
    query=SQL(
        "CREATE USER {id} WITH PASSWORD {password}".format(
            id=id
            password=password
        )
    )
    try:
        self.cur.execute(
            query=query
        )
    except DuplicateObject:
        print("{id} User already created.".format(id=id))
    else:
        print("{id} User create.".format(id=id))
```

in the code below

```
query=SQL(
    "CREATE USER {id} WITH PASSWORD {password}".format(
        id=id
        password=password
    )
)
```

I am trying to use the class of the sql module for the id and password variables of the query.

```
id=Identifier(id)
password=SQL(password)
```

like the code above.

Using identifiers and SQL will result in a syntax error.
Which class fits the id password variable?

Comment: take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022587/postgres-psycopg2-create-user

Comment: `password = sql.Literal(password)`. It is good idea to use the `sql` module namespace, it makes it clearer where things are coming from.

Comment: Actually it would be safer to do: `qry = sql.SQL("CREATE USER {id} WITH PASSWORD %s").format(id=sql.Identifier('dog'))` then: `cur.execute(qry, ['test'])`. Then the password string would be properly escaped.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Applying the identifier class to the id variable throws an error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Is the ID an identifier in postgresql?

Comment: What is the complete error  message? The code worked for me. A `user`(actually a role) name is an object so it is an identifier. Trying it as a `Literal()` fails as a SQL()`  works but you don't get proper escaping.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you. Do you usually use literal classes for values that do not change?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I understand the use of identifier classes for user ids.